# Google google-custom-search how to search more:social

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using google-custom-search and trying to run `more:social` kind of search.
it is possible from the javascript, for example: `&q="bill clinton" more:socail&`  .

Is there something similar in the api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

more: tokens should work in the 'q' parameter of the API the same way they work as from the Search Element